# "Verrentung": retirement or "pensionification"?

Tags: translation

[This article](https://www.gdv.de/de/medien/aktuell/studie--nur-rente-sichert-lebenslanges-einkommen---deutsche-unterschaetzen-lebenserwartung-34046) has the following sentence:

> Obwohl laut Forsa fast 60 Prozent der Menschen planen, mindestens 80
>   Prozent ihres Lebensunterhalts mit fixen Rentenzahlungen bestreiten zu
>   wollen, entscheiden sie sich häufig gegen eine Verrentung ihrer
>   Ersparnisse.

I am guessing that "Verrentung ihrer Ersparnisse" means "buying a pension plan using their savings", but is this valid usage? In all dictionaries the only meaning given of "Verrentung" is simply "Retirement", not "buying a pension plan", or "Pensionification".

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verrenten, meaning 2

Comment: Some examples, even though this meaning is not mentioned: https://www.dwds.de/wb/verrenten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give a self-contained answer:

*Verrentung* means, monthly payments for returning of the investment (i. e. repayment) as opposed to a single, or several (typically one per year for fiscal reasons) payments.

So your money is already at the institution and you simple choose, in which intervals to get it back.

Comment: Ok, so it's basically an annuity.

Answer (score 3):

You may get a first answer by looking up the meaning of *ver-* in/on (?) [online Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ver_). According to meaning 2 *ver-* can mean

> drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven oder Adjektiven und einer Endung aus, dass eine Person oder Sache zu etwas gemacht, in einen bestimmten Zustand versetzt, in etwas umgesetzt wird.

So you may call the transformation of savings into a monthly payed pension "Verrentung".

Googling "Ersparnisse verrenten", you will have a few hits. Nominalisation - here *verrenten* > *Verrentung* - is a common technique in official language, and googling "Verrentung * Ersparnisse" will provide some further hits. "Verrentung * Kapital" gives a much longer google hit list.

In *eine Buchvorlage verfilmen*, *wehrlose Menchen versklaven*, *einen Gedanken versinnbildlichen* the meanig of *ver-* is very similar to *ein Kapital verrenten*. All three can be nominalised: *Verfilmung, Versklavung, Versinnbildlichung*.

It is correct to say that *Verrentung*, especially *Frühverrentung* or *Zwangsverrentung*, refer to persons going voluntarily or enforcedly on pension. That would be Duden meaning 3 of *ver-*:

> drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven und einer Endung aus, dass eine Person oder Sache mit etwas versehen wird.

In this case the meaning would be that a person is "pensioned" in the sense of "*mit einer Rente 'versehen'"* or "*durch eine Rente versorgt*" or in more common German "*bekommt eine Rente*".

I think you can understand *Verrentung einer Person* also as a transformation:  The status of the person changes from a *Berufstätiger* (working person) to a *Rentner / Person im Ruhestand* (retired person), which means a massive and very often imposed change in the person's social rank and explains the existence of the word *Zwangsverrentung*, giving the idea of *jemand wird in Rente geschickt / muss (in Rente) gehen*.